# Find the element providing a priority date

Tags: priority, ppa, france

A certain patent claims a priority date (just under one year prior to the application date) and I would like to find the element providing this priority.

The priority number points towards France (FR index in EPO priority number) but at the time of application, France did not offer a system similar to Provisional Patent Application if I'm not mistaken (only since 2019) so I guess it must be something else than a PPA.

However, I'm not sure how to search for the element providing priority, when I use the priority number in searches it points to the said patent (by finding the priority number it claims).

I'm a little lost I guess.

Comment: If you provide the patent number you might get a specific answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priority, internationally, is under the Paris Convention. It has nothing to do with the idea of a provisional application, although a US provisional can as as a priority document under Paris. The number will be the application number of a French patent application. I would look it up in Espacenet at https://worldwide.espacenet.com/

Comment: I would proceed this way. If no luck, then I would try to retrieve the priority document via the Register (e.g. EPO Register, USPTO Public Pair, etc.) of the Patent Office corresponding to the (second) patent application that claims priority from the priority patent application. For the priority to be effective, the priority application needs be furnished for the later patent application, thus the document should be available in the Register upon meeting this requirement.